# Is it possible to build Apache Spark against Hadoop 2.5.1

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark

After compiling Hadoop 2.5.1 with maven 
    hadoop version
    Hadoop 2.5.1, I tried to compile apache spark using the following command:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.5.1 -Pdeb -DskipTests clean package
```

But apparently there is no 2.5 profile.

My question is : what should I do?

1. rebuild hadoop 2.4
2. or compile spark with profile 2.4
3. or any other solution ?

Comment: You could try to create a profile for it in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml) -- look for the string "hadoop-2.4' near the bottom and create for 2.5. That should deal with the obvious HDFS protocol compatibility issues. I can imagine all sorts of things going wrong but it may not be too expensive to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was asked after the poster inquired:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-1-1-0-with-Hadoop-2-5-0-td15827.html

"The hadoop-2.4 profile is really intended to be "Hadoop 2.4+". It 
should compile and run fine with Hadoop 2.5 as far as I know. CDH 5.2 
is Hadoop 2.5 + Spark 1.1, so there is evidence it works."

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the profile name worked for me. 
Thx for the answers.